# Simple tutorial for consuming RESTful API from Flash (AS3)?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, api, rest

I've built a simple RESTful API for game developers to do things like authenticate against our user store, post scores, and get leaderboards. It's not perfect, but it's very well documented and is working pretty well for 50% of game developers.

The other 50% seem to be Flash developers who just don't get the idea of a RESTful API. I really don't want to build a wrapper for these developers—I'm not a Flash developer, have no interest in becoming one, and really want to keep everything about our API technology-agnostic.

Can anyone recommend a good tutorial on how to consume a RESTful API for Flash developers?

Comment: As a Flash developer, I'm now curious to see your API and figure out which group I'm in :)

Answer (score 0):

Given my experience with this problem, I suspect this may have less to do with the fact that the developers don't understand the API and more to do with the limitations of the flash player:  it simply doesn't support the full range of HTTP methods (at least, not without a proxy) you've probably used in your RESTful API implementation (such as PUT and DELETE).

Flash only supports GET and POST.

If this is indeed the issue, you'll need to offer an alternative to the missing HTTP verbs.  I've worked around this in the past by using POST and adding a 'method=http_method' parameter to the query string.

Another gotcha could be your lack of a [crossdomain.xml](http://curtismorley.com/2007/09/01/flash-flex-tutorial-how-to-create-a-crossdomainxml-file/) file.

Comment: The API only uses GET and POST (like I said, it's not perfect) so I doubt that's the problem.